# Xamarin Forms Path losing ScaleTransform after Trigger

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms for Android. My Problem is with a `Path` UI Element. This UI Element has a `ScaleTransform` where the image is scaled 1.5x in X and Y direction. In addition it has a `DataTrigger` which changes the `Fill` and the `Data` properties according to the status of `bool IsConnected`. If `IsConnected` switches states the appropriate trigger is executed but the image loses its scale and stays smaller even if the state changes back.

This is my Xaml code:

```
<Path Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Data="Some Geometry">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
    <Path.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Path" Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Path" Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="Some Other Geometry"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>
</Path>
```

This behaviour is surprising to me. Can someone suggest a solutuin to this?
I have searched the internet for answers but could not find anything similar.

Edit: It seems that the problem is that `Data` property is changed. If only the `Fill` property is changed the scale stays the same.

On request my Path Data:

(Some Geometry)

`Data="M12,21L15.6,16.2C14.6,15.45 13.35,15 12,15C10.65,15 9.4,15.45 8.4,16.2L12,21M12,3C7.95,3 4.21,4.34 1.2,6.6L3,9C5.5,7.12 8.62,6 12,6C15.38,6 18.5,7.12 21,9L22.8,6.6C19.79,4.34 16.05,3 12,3M12,9C9.3,9 6.81,9.89 4.8,11.4L6.6,13.8C8.1,12.67 9.97,12 12,12C14.03,12 15.9,12.67 17.4,13.8L19.2,11.4C17.19,9.89 14.7,9 12,9Z"`

(Some Other Geometry)

`Value="M2.28,3L1,4.27L2.47,5.74C2.04,6 1.61,6.29 1.2,6.6L3,9C3.53,8.6 4.08,8.25 4.66,7.93L6.89,10.16C6.15,10.5 5.44,10.91 4.8,11.4L6.6,13.8C7.38,13.22 8.26,12.77 9.2,12.47L11.75,15C10.5,15.07 9.34,15.5 8.4,16.2L12,21L14.46,17.73L17.74,21L19,19.72M12,3C9.85,3 7.8,3.38 5.9,4.07L8.29,6.47C9.5,6.16 10.72,6 12,6C15.38,6 18.5,7.11 21,9L22.8,6.6C19.79,4.34 16.06,3 12,3M12,9C11.62,9 11.25,9 10.88,9.05L14.07,12.25C15.29,12.53 16.43,13.07 17.4,13.8L19.2,11.4C17.2,9.89 14.7,9 12,9Z"`

Comment: Why you want to change Path.Data when IsConnected becomes false ? Is the data same as the original one ? Could you provide the data to us for test ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT The Data should be completely irellevant. Either way I'll add my two data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because the `RenderTransform` only works once for the `Some Geometry` but not `Some Other Geometry` .

If you want to keep the `Scale` on the path , put the `Data` and `RenderTransform` into `Triggers` as well and place `RenderTransform` at the last .

```
 <Path Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" >
       
        <Path.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Path" Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>

                <Setter Property="Data" Value="M12,21L15.6,16.2C14.6,15.45 13.35,15 12,15C10.65,15 9.4,15.45 8.4,16.2L12,21M12,3C7.95,3 4.21,4.34 1.2,6.6L3,9C5.5,7.12 8.62,6 12,6C15.38,6 18.5,7.12 21,9L22.8,6.6C19.79,4.34 16.05,3 12,3M12,9C9.3,9 6.81,9.89 4.8,11.4L6.6,13.8C8.1,12.67 9.97,12 12,12C14.03,12 15.9,12.67 17.4,13.8L19.2,11.4C17.19,9.89 14.7,9 12,9Z"/>
                <Setter Property="RenderTransform" >
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="10.5" ScaleY="10.5"/>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Path" Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
               
                <Setter Property="Data" Value="M2.28,3L1,4.27L2.47,5.74C2.04,6 1.61,6.29 1.2,6.6L3,9C3.53,8.6 4.08,8.25 4.66,7.93L6.89,10.16C6.15,10.5 5.44,10.91 4.8,11.4L6.6,13.8C7.38,13.22 8.26,12.77 9.2,12.47L11.75,15C10.5,15.07 9.34,15.5 8.4,16.2L12,21L14.46,17.73L17.74,21L19,19.72M12,3C9.85,3 7.8,3.38 5.9,4.07L8.29,6.47C9.5,6.16 10.72,6 12,6C15.38,6 18.5,7.11 21,9L22.8,6.6C19.79,4.34 16.06,3 12,3M12,9C11.62,9 11.25,9 10.88,9.05L14.07,12.25C15.29,12.53 16.43,13.07 17.4,13.8L19.2,11.4C17.2,9.89 14.7,9 12,9Z"/>

                <Setter Property="RenderTransform" >
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="10.5" ScaleY="10.5"/>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
```

Comment: Thanks. So this is not a corner i could cut. ^^